# TableView Cell Spin Top To Bottom Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3

For my little project, I need your help. I've already created a functioning table view. Now I want the rows animation to go from the top to bottom  and scroll on button click. And when click on stop button, the tableview cell should stop at a particular cell . How do I do that?

Screen Shot Below:

1. Spin Button:

   [image: Spin Button Screen Shot]
2. Click on Spin button:

   [image: Click on Spin button Screen Shot]
3. When Click on Stop Button.

   [image: Stop Button Screen Shot]

Can someone please explain to me how to set this type of animation on tableview cell  or  any  other  view, i've tried to solve this but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use collectionview + customise layout + infinite scrolling.

Comment: Okay @dahiya_boy if you don't mind please give me some hint or some code ?

Comment: It is too broad.. so in which point you need help??

Comment: From starting to end because i don't know how to make this type of spinning, if you don't mind help me.

Comment: @samdhiman I have added answer, If you find it useful then upvote and mark as correct.

Comment: ya sure i will check, Thank you very much dear @SayaliShinde

Comment: Have you even tried something?

Comment: yes some animation but no results yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITableViewDelegate` method, for getting table view scrolling event and when this method gets called you can start timer stating repeat to true with continuing scrolling. And when Stop button is clicked you can invalidate timer. Use below function to scroll infinite until you clicked Stop button.

```
var indexOfPageToRequest = 1

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

// calculates where the user is in the y-axis

let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {

    // increments the number of the page to request
    indexOfPageToRequest += 1

    // call your API for more data
    loadSaved(indexOfPageToRequest)

    // tell the table view to reload with the new data
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i m confused how to call this method in button action